# По заданному числу N определить максимальную степень числа K, которая делит N! (нацело)

Tags: c++

Ограничение времени:    1 с
Ограничение реального времени:  5 с
Ограничение памяти: 64М

**Задание**:
По заданному числу N определить максимальную степень числа K, которая делит N! (нацело).

**Формат входных данных**:
Первая строка содержит одно число T (1 ≤ T ≤ 1000) (количество тестовых случаев).
Следующие T строк содержат по 2 числа N (1 ≤ N ≤ 1,000,000,000) и K (2 ≤ K ≤ 100), разделенных пробелом.

**Формат результата**:
Для каждого тестового случая в отдельной строке выведите максимальную степень.

**Примеры**:

Входные данные:

---

2

5 2

2 3

---

выход (он происходит сразу после ввода 5 2, например 3):

---

3

0

---

Подскажите алгоритм, пожалуйста, весь код не надо, кусочек можно. :)

Если считать факториал, допустим, макс. числа 1,000,000,000, то умрет компьютер + время. Мне сказали, что можно через разложение на простые множители, но я не совсем понимаю как.
Заранее благодарен!

P.S. Любой другой алгоритм тоже с удовольствием рассмотрю!

Comment: Дубликат темы. Готовое решение - первое в связанных темах: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/174008/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C/464482#464482

Comment: В последнем ответе - всё, что нужно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Число K раскладываем на множители в виде число-степень:

```
4 -> (2:2)
10 -> (2:1, 5:1)
12 -> (2:2, 3:1)
```

(в коде это будет просто массив структур).

Дальше в цикле от 2 и до N делим текущее число последовательно на все основания, сколько можно.

```
N = 5, K = 6 (2:1, 3:1)
2 - будет только один раз делиться на 2 (1,0)
3 - только один раз на 3  (1,1)
4 - два раза на два (3,1)
5 -  не делиться
```

В скобках я показал "счет" по каждому делителю.

Теперь только осталось посчитать, результат. Так как в моем случае K раскладывается на множители в первой степени, то достаточно взять минимальное в конечном массиве. В общем случае, нужно поделить нацело "попарно" и взять минимум.

Пример номер два. K=12 (2:2, 3:1), N = 10

```
2 -> (1,0)
3 -> (1,1)
4 -> (3,1)
5 -> (3,1)
6 -> (4,2)
7 -> (4,2)
8 -> (7,2)
9 -> (7,4)
10 -> (8,4)
```

(8,4) / (2,1) = (4,4). Минимум равен 4. Значит 10! делиться на 12 в степени 4

Comment: А вот в примере 2: (8,4) / (2,1) = (4,4). Откуда 2,1? Это степени от простых чисел K?

Comment: да, 10 = 2^1 * 5^1

Comment: Т.е. приходим к каноническим разложениям чисел. Нерациональный способ.

Comment: А почему во втором примере 6 -> (4,2)? Разве не 6/2 = 3 и 6/3 = 2?

Comment: Там `6!=1*2*3*4*5*6=720`. Если это разложить на множители, то будет 2 в 4 степени, 3 в второй и 5. Вот и получилось. Ещё раз - это факториал.

Comment: Благодарю, но ограничение по времени стоит 1 с, а n <= 1,000,000,000. Разве цикл перебора от 2 до n не выйдет за пределы этого ограничения?

Answer (score 3):

Корректирую свой ответ из [похожей темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/174008/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%83-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0?lq=1)

Если число `p` простое, то из теории чисел ([разложение факториала](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/factorial_divisors)) следует, что

**N!#p = [N/p] + [N/p<sup>2</sup>] + ... + [N/p<sup>t</sup>],**
где:

`[a]` - целая часть числа `a`,
`a#p` - показатель простого числа `p` в каноническом разложении числа `a`.

При этом t = [log<sub>p</sub> N], а практически

**t= [ln(N+0.5) / ln p]**

В нашем случае `K` - составное, т.е. имеет каноническое разложение вида

**K=p<sub>0</sub><sup>r<sub>0</sub></sup> * p<sub>1</sub><sup>r<sub>1</sub></sup> ... * p<sub>s</sub><sup>r<sub>s</sub></sup>,**

[алгоритм факторизации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB) можно выбрать по вкусу (для обеспечения быстродействия простые множители проверять при условии **p<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> <= K**, а если множитель p<sub>i</sub> найден, то этот и последующие множители искать у меньшего числа **K/p<sub>i</sub>**, соответственно сужая диапазон поиска).

Поэтому

**deg = min<sub>i=0...s</sub>{[N!#p<sub>i</sub> / r<sub>i</sub>]}.**