# Количество нулей в числе n! в системе счисления 225

Tags: c++, алгоритм, системы-счисления

Дано целое число 1 < n < 10^9. 
Надо написать программу на С++, которая ищет количество нулей в числе n! в системе счисления 225. Нужен какой-то хитрый алгоритм, что-бы не искать сам факториал, ибо он огромен.

Comment: Возможно, количество нулей в конце числа?

Comment: чую попытка посчитать факториал `N=10^9-1` очень быстро закончится `OutOfMemoryException`  :)

Comment: @teran Если не ошибаюсь, 9 гигабайт для записи должно хватить :)

Comment: В более общем виде это было [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/174008/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%83-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0/464482#464482)

Answer (score 6):

Вам нужно по сути подсчитать, на какую степень 255 делится число n! Поскольку разложение 225 на простые множители — 5² × 3², вам нужно подсчитать степень 5 и степень 3, на которую делится ваше число.

Согласно [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB#.D0.A0.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.BD.D0.B0_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D1.87.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.B0), степень `k` простого числа `p`, на которую делится `n!` вычисляется так:

```
int maxPowerOf(int p, int n)
{
    int k = 0;
    int powerOfP = 1;
    while (true)
    {
        powerOfP *= p;
        int addend = n / powerOfP;
        if (addend == 0)
            return k;
        k += addend;
    }
}
```

Имея это, вы вычисляете ваши степени:

```
int p3 = maxPowerOf(3, n);
int p5 = maxPowerOf(5, n);
```

Степени чисел 9 и 25, на которые делится `n!`, равны соответственно

```
int p9 = p3 / 2;
int p25 = p5 / 2;
```

(поскольку 25 = 5² и 9 = 3²),
и искомая степень числа 225, на которую делится `n!`, есть

```
min(p9, p25)
```

---

Пока я писал ответ, @Harry уже написал то же самое. Оставляю только из-за кода.

Comment: Можно упомянуть, что `min(p3, p25) == p25` для `n!` и `p25 = p5 // 2` так как `25==5**2`. [Похоже работает](http://ideone.com/IlESLp)

Answer (score 5):

225 - это 9*25. Тройки входят в факториал куда чаще, так что нужно считать пятерки.

Пересчитайте количество вхождений пятерок. Сначала - кратные 5 - их `n/5` (деления целочисленные). Потом - кратные 25 - `n/25`. Потом - 125... И так далее, и просуммируйте их все. Так как нам нужны 25 - поделите на 2. Это и будет количество нулей. Если, конечно, имеется в виду количество нулей в конце числа :)

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

По моим расчетам, для 1000000000! количество искомых нулей - 124999999.